# Função Focus TextBox e Verificar se está preenchido

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso de uma função que ao clicar no textbox se ele tiver vazio fica de uma cor, e se preenchido mude a cor, mas somente quando clicar nele, como posso fazer? 
Se não tiver preenchido vou chamar esta função:

```js
function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
```

E se tiver, vou chamar esta:

```js
function (element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
```

Edição: 
Tenho este campo no modal, por exemplo:

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtHora" runat="server" class="form-control" onblur="Verifica_Hora(this);"></asp:TextBox>
  <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
</div>
```

Já tenho a função que funciona se eu colocar required:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-group input[required], .input-group textarea[required], .input-group select[required]').on('keyup change', function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
      $group = $(this).closest('.input-group'),
      $addon = $group.find('.input-group-addon'),
      $icon = $addon.find('span'),
      state = false;

    if (!$group.data('validate')) {
      state = $(this).val() ? true : false;
    } else if ($group.data('validate') == "email") {
      state = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test($(this).val())
    } else if ($group.data('validate') == 'phone') {
      state = /^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/.test($(this).val())
    } else if ($group.data('validate') == "length") {
      state = $(this).val().length >= $group.data('length') ? true : false;
    } else if ($group.data('validate') == "number") {
      state = !isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) && isFinite($(this).val());
    }
    if (state) {
      $addon.removeClass('danger');
      $addon.addClass('success');
      $icon.attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
    } else {
      $addon.removeClass('success');
      $addon.addClass('danger');
      $icon.attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk');
    }

  });

  $('.input-group input[required], .input-group textarea[required], 
.input-group select[required]').trigger('change');


});
```

Se for preenchido, ele muda a imagem do asterisco para o ok.
E este, muda o textbox de vermelho para normal, caso seja digitado algo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
      txtNome: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(element) {
      element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
  });

});
```

Só que estes dois só funcionam fora do modal. Então no modal preciso verificar os campos, ao ser clicado, e ao ser digitado algo. Não consegui fazer o modal funcionar com required, pois se coloco required, eu não consigo fazer abrir o modal com o click do button.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```js
function valid(element) {
  $(element)
    .closest('.control-group')
    .removeClass('error')
    .addClass('success');
}

function notValid(element) {
  $(element)
    .closest('.control-group')
    .removeClass('success')
    .addClass('error');
}


$('#textbox').on('focus change', function() {
  if (! $(this).val() || $(this).val().length === 0) {
    return notValid($(this));
  }
  
  valid($(this));
});
```

```css
.success {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.error {
  border: solid 1px  red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="control-group">
  <textarea id="textbox">Teste</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Não deu certo Luiz Felipe, os campos que vou precisar fazer esta verificação é textbox, eu tenho a função pronta pro required, porém por estar no modal eu não consigo fazer abrir o modal se colocar o required nos campos dentro. Vou precisar chamar essa função em vários textboxs.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, para uma melhor esclarecida.

Answer (score 0):

Basta capturar o evento `click` para tratar quando o campo for clicado
Se quiser também remover o efeito quando sair, basta usar o evento `blur`:

```js
$('#i').click(function() {
 if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).addClass('vazio');
           $(this).removeClass('preeenchido');
        } else {
      $(this).removeClass('vazio');
           $(this).addClass('preeenchido');  
        }
});


$('#i').blur(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('preeenchido');
  $(this).removeClass('vazio');

});
```

```css
input {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 200px
}

.vazio {
  background-color: cyan
}

.preeenchido {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='i' />
```

Se quiser também fazer isso quando o elemento estiver com focus (clicado ou movido com tab) pode usar o evento `focus` no lugar do `click`

Comment: Não funcionou Ricardo, editei a pergunta, para maiores esclarecimentos.

Comment: Vamos lá, o que não funcionou? Chegou a colocar o evento `onclick`  no TextBox apenas para teste, pra ver se exibe pelo menos um `alert`? Algo assim: `$('#txtHora').click(function() { alert('clicou'); });`

Comment: Lembre que um `TextBox` com `runat="server"` não aceita um evento `onclick` no javascript, se colocar `OnClick` será executado um evento server, por isso é importante associar o evento click através do próprio javascript, como no exemplo do comentário acima

Comment: Na verdade Ricardo eu não posso tirar o runat=server, pois utilizo o campo para várias coisas, e teria que mudar toda a lógica, tem alguma forma que consigo contornar este problema ? no caso o click não ira funcionar no javascript mesmo então.

Comment: Funciona se você associar o evento no próprio javascript, assim: `$('#txtHora').click(function() { .... seu código });`  se fosse um `asp:Buttom`, teria o evento `OnClientClick` que resolveria, mas o `TextBox` não tem

Comment: Coloquei a função do txthora  com click, porém ele não retorna o alert.

Comment: Tentei desta forma, porém o modal nem abre, tanto com onchange ou como blur.   $(function () {
            $("#txtHora").live("keyup change", function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "") {
                    alert('campo obrigatorio')
                }

            });
        });